# best type of bulb in glass ceiling fixture

Tags: lighting

what is the safest type of bulb to use in a glass ceiling enclosure, now that the 60w incondecents are no more ?   Would it be Halogen, CFL or LED ?

Answer (score 3):

LEDs are completely the win.  That is the way to go.  They last 30 years (probably longer, realistically, no one knows). You can get them in any color temperature or CRI you want, you don't need to get harsh LED if you don't want to.

CFL is dead.   It was only ever a "gap technology" to temporarily gain efficiency until LED manufacturing was able to catch up.

Incandescents will be around for a long time, in improved forms such as halogen.  They aren't that efficient, they get hot, and they burn out.  Only use them if you have an engineering requirement for incandescents *specifically* (such as a doghouse warmer, or oven light).

Comment: There's one kicker you didn't mention. LED bulbs generate some heat and are somewhat heat sensative. The OP should make sure that any he buys are not marked "not for enclosed fixtures". Enclosed fixtures may trap the heat and cause the bulb to overheat.

Comment: 2 points: not all LED bulbs get hot or as hot as the worst, dimming slightly drastically cuts heat.

Answer (score 0):

The trick, as alluded to in DoxyLover's comment, is that you mentioned a "glass ceiling **enclosure**" and virtually all LED and CFL bulbs contra-indicate being installed in such fixtures.

The lifetime of the bulb may be drastically reduced due to overheating in that application.

A halogen bulb does not mind being hot. Likewise, I'm fairly sure you can still get "conventional incandescent" appliance bulbs, but a halogen will be somewhat more efficient and may last longer.

Alternatively, you may decide to change the fixture to one that is not "enclosed" so that you can use LEDs without drastically impacting their life and performance. If doing that, consider a "from the ground up" LED fixture - from a reputable maker those are better than bulbs, as the fixture can be designed to optimize performance without having to conform to a form-factor from 120 (140?) years ago that does not make cooling easy. From sketchy makers bulbs are a better bet, as they are easily replaced.

Comment: If the original enclosed fixture was a ceiling fixture designed for incandescent bulbs, wouldn't it be vented to keep the fixture from overheating? Or are there fixtures which are designed so that the outer sheet metal will get *very* hot, but the installation requirement specify a stand-off distance or gap from combustible materials? Such a fixture would not get hot enough to damage an incandescent bulb, but which could or would damage an LED. Do such fixtures exist? Could one simply drill vent holes in the sheet metal? Could the glass be replaced with a coarse metal screen?